# Can I do film simulations in-camera without a Fuji camera?

Tags: camera-settings, in-camera-processing

I've been watching a lot of youtube videos where people praise Fuji's film simulation modes (though mostly to get a filmic, cinematic look for video) and I've been getting intrigued by Fuji enthusiast [film simulation "recipes"](https://fujixweekly.com/recipes/). But I don't want to buy a Fuji camera.

Is there a way to do film simulations in-camera if I shoot a different brand of camera?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there is a way, but generally it's without Fuji's sophisticated film color science. And if you're expecting whatever you shoot to come out of camera looking like you shot it on film, you could be disappointed. This is mostly about tweaking colors, contrast, and saturation.   Most manufacturers don't give the same level of control over specific factors, such as grain. And even with Fuji, older bodies have fewer controls for film simulation recipes.

But most camera manufacturers do allow users to create custom processing presets that can be applied in-camera, though you may have to shoot JPEG or use scene modes to get there:

- Canon: [Picture Styles](https://global.canon/en/imaging/picturestyle/) with a [Picture Style Editor](https://global.canon/en/imaging/picturestyle/editor/index.html)
- Sony: [Picture Profiles](https://helpguide.sony.net/ilc/1420/v1/en/contents/TP0000435736.html)
- Nikon: [Picture Controls](https://www.nikonusa.com/en/learn-and-explore/a/tips-and-techniques/picture-controls-step-by-step.html) with a [Picture Control Utility](https://downloadcenter.nikonimglib.com/en/products/163/Picture_Control_Utility_2.html) editor
- Pentax/Ricoh: [Custom Image](https://www.ricoh-imaging.co.jp/english/products/custom_image/) settings (e.g., [Ritchie's Ricoh Recipes](https://www.ricohrecipes.com/))

A lot of enterprising folks who love to create film simulation profiles both publish recipes (e.g., [Nikon Z recipes](https://fujixweekly.com/2022/07/03/11-nikon-z-film-simulation-recipes/)) and/or offer/sell uploadable profiles (in the case of Canon, where profiles can be created and saved off as .pf2 or .pf3 files and then [loaded onto a camera body using EOS Utility](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=D3BdqWdnFaw)). [Thomas Fransson](https://thomasfransson.gumroad.com/) offers free profiles and Le Hung does paid profiles. For Sony users, veresdenialex has recipes you can pay to access.

Similarly, you can find flatter profiles for video color grading if your camera doesn't come with log profiles. Technicolor, for example, [published Canon profiles for Cinestyle](https://www.technicolor.com/cinestyle).

It's still probably going to give you a lot more control and better quality simulation to do this as desktop post-processing with tools designed specifically for film simulation. But there is a way to do this.